# How to automatically fill in a form on click?

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a very simple form (FormAPI, not Webform) and the behavior when clicking the submit button is to both send an email and insert the form values into the database.

Under this same form, I have a database query which allows me to print a list of all latest form submissions. I'd like to add a "reuse this submission" link next to each form submission and would like this link to fill in the (empty) form fields to easily reuse past submissions, optionally tweak them a bit, and send them again easily.

I'm pretty sure it needs Ajax/Javascript and wonder how complicated it would be to implement this? Maybe alternatives exist and I'd be interested in those options as well to achieve this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Very confusing. What does email has to do with your question? what is your problem? Installing prepopulate, writing a callback that sends a list of links formatted for prepopulate or firing that callback from AJAX?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to add confusion here. I was trying to give context but obviously this is not helpful so forget the email part please. The prepopulate module might be interesting (didn't know it). I never had to deal with that kind of requirement before and I'm a starting developer so I don't really know where to look so I'm seeking advices or code sample to dig further.

Comment: Better tracked here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41762/populate-form-when-clicking-on-a-link