# Populate form when clicking on a link

Tags: forms, ajax

I have a very simple form created with Form API (Drupal 7) and the latest entries are displayed within a sidebar block and are also clickable.

[image: Form and last entries sidebar block]

I'd like that when I click on any recent entry, it pre-fills the form automatically with these values but I don't know how to achieve this. Googling brought me to:

- http://drupal.org/node/752056
- http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate
- http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html

And I've also seen something that could be of interest with JS:

```
$("#edit-id").value('newvalue')
```

The thing is I'm very new to coding and would like more step by step examples to achieve this. I feel like Ajax would be the best solution here, to make a DB call when needed ans populate the form.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Anyone? Any pointers would help greatly.